# PyGTK Drag And Drop - "motion" signal not raised, can't change button appearance

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, gtk, pygtk

I'm using Drag And Drop on two PyGTK widgets - a simple `Label`, and a `FileChooserButton`. Both seem to work correctly.

However, I'd like to have the appearance of the widget to change when the mouse is over it, so the user will have a clue that it can receive a drop.

Is there a way to automatically do it? I tried to implement it manually with the `drag_motion` signal, but it's never raised...

Here's a simple example, based on http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq23.031.htp :

```
import gtk

TARGET_TYPE_URI_LIST = 80
dnd_list = [ ( 'text/uri-list', 0, TARGET_TYPE_URI_LIST ) ]

def on_drag_data_received(widget, context, x, y, selection, target_type, timestamp):
    print "DND received"

def on_drag_motion(self, widget, context, x, y, timestamp):
    print "DND motion"

w = gtk.Window()
w.connect('drag_data_received', on_drag_data_received)
w.connect('drag_motion', on_drag_motion)
w.drag_dest_set( gtk.DEST_DEFAULT_MOTION | gtk.DEST_DEFAULT_HIGHLIGHT | gtk.DEST_DEFAULT_DROP,
                 dnd_list, gtk.gdk.ACTION_COPY)

w.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

`DND received` is printed, but it never prints `DND motion`. What's wrong?..

Answer (score 0):

You mixed the arguments (copy paste needs a focused user...;-)

drag motion arguments are:

`widget, context, x, y, time_`

but you have:

`self, widget, context, x, y, timestamp`